# Pyomo instances in python multithreading

Tags: multithreading, python-3.6, pyomo

I am trying to solve a stochastic problem. The problem for 24 steps and in each step I solve it for 450 different instances.
Now it is possible to solve the problem serially, but that takes a lot of time, so i wanted to solve those 450 instances parallely.

I approached this in 2 ways:

using solver_manager and multiple pyro mip servers. Here I just have to queue the insances and the solver manager would assign the problems to pyro mip servers. But the pyro mip servers occupy a lot of memory and retain it even after the final result is computed.
using opt solver.
a) I can solve using the opt solver directly, but it is slow.
b) using multi threading. I tried to create a threadPoolExecutor with 5 threads and then solve those 450 instances in different threads. But just shifting to multithreading causes the pyomo to throw errors.

```py
def optimize():
    optsolver = SolverFactory(self.solver_name)
    value = self.initialize_all_values()
    for timestep in range(24):
        instance_list = self.create_instance_list(value)
        futures = {}
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            for instance_object in instance_list:
                futures = {executor.submit(self.thread_solver, instance_object["instance"], optsolver, timestep)}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                try:
                    result = future.result()
                    value.update(result)
                except Exception as e:
                    self.logger.error(e)


def thread_solver(instance, optsolver, timestep):
    result = optsolver.solve(instance)
    if (result.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (
            result.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):

        instance.solutions.load_from(result)

        my_dict = {}
        for v in instance.component_objects(Var, active=True):
            varobject = getattr(instance, str(v))
            var_list = []
            try:
                for index in varobject:
                    var_list.append(varobject[index].value)
                my_dict[str(v)] = var_list
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.error("error reading result " + str(e))

        value = {key: my_dict[k][0]}
        return value

    elif result.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible:
        self.logger.info("Termination condition is infeasible")
        return {}
    else:
        self.logger.info("Nothing fits")
        return {}
```

I get the following errors/outputs:

Nothing fits
Solver failed to locate input problem file: /usr/src/app/temp/pyomo/tmpn23yhmz_.pyomo.lp
I have set the pyomo temp file location to "/usr/src/app/temp/pyomo"
The same code runs perfectly fine without multithreading.
Any reason for the pyomo to not solve the problem?

UPDATE 1:
I tried using mutex when I try to call the optsolver.solve(instance). This helped in reducing the above error and not completely eliminate. Whenever these error occur, I tried to solve the instance again and in the second attemp they would be solved. So, multithreading does work but I don't know why the errors still occur.

Comment: Maybe you could try multiprocessing rather than multithreading. I have some prototype code sitting in a pull request (haven't had time to get to it) that might be helpful for you: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/963/files

Comment: I tried multiprocessing, however, due to the requirement of paramters to pickle-able, I am not able to run it. I create a preprocessed data dict from input data which i use to instantiate the abstract pyomo model. It would be counter positive to create the data dict inside each process call, as it would likely increase the run time and processing load.

Comment: Your data dict is not pickleable? If it is dillable, you can try using `pathos`.